# Zoom Factor for Crystal Report 10 Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net

In our report of an ASP.NET Application we are not able to change the zoom factor once we chose a particular zoom factor value.
For example
  The initial report has a default zoom factor of 100 when we change the zoom factor to 200 and we are able to view it properly but when we again try to change zoom factor to 300 or 100 we are not able to do so or rather the zoom value doesn't changes. 
can anyone help us on the above

Comment: Hi, we have observed that above mentioned behavior is occurring in some of our reports in the remaining reports we can change the zoom factor multiple items. Please be noted that we are using the existing old reports which is developed in VB6 Application and taking the same report from the old application and pasting it in vs 2008.

Comment: Update, we found out that only on those report in which Selection Formula is applied we are not able to change the zoom factor on those report in which no selection formula is applied we are able to change zoom factor multiple times.The Selection formula is applied from the code behind as follows 'Code'                             if (Session["CryRSelectionFormula"] != null)
                    {
                        CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = Session["CryRSelectionFormula"].ToString();
                    } Can anyone help on the above please.